# Cassandra switching node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Do I require a router to switch node when a node is down?

I am using

*jdbc:cassandra:root/root@localhost:9160/MyKeyspace*

to connect with cassandra but when the node is down how do I switch it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a cassandra cluster, then all the nodes would be interconnected and the driver would handle the switching of nodes. Cassandra is a AP database, so availability should never be a problem

Comment: I am confused as I am supplying only a single IP in connection url.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. The datastax drivers need only one node to connect to all the other nodes

Comment: What happens when that node goes down?

Comment: If your connection is a singleton and you persist the connection, nothing would happen. However if it tries to connect again and the node is not available, then reconnection will not be possible. In that case you should specify two or three nodes. I use three nodes for a 8 node cluster. Haven't had a problem with that yet